# How to make some text repeatedly show and hide?

Tags: jquery, css

I am trying to get some flashing effect by jQuery.
Please help. Here is the not-working code.

Javascript:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
     var flashThis = function(){
        var className = $('#annoying').attr('class');
        if(className.indexOf("blueOne") !== -1) {
           jQuery("#annoying").removeClass("blueOne");
        }
        if(className.indexOf("blueOne") === -1) {
           jQuery("#annoying").addClass("blueOne");
        }
        flashThis();
     }

     flashThis();
  });
```

CSS:

```
   .whiteOne {
      color:#FFFFFF;
   }
   .blueOne {
      color:#0000FF;
   }
```

HTML:

`<p id="annoying" class="whiteOne">I will flash.</p>`

Comment: you created an infinite loop with 0 delay.

Answer (score 2):

Try this instead:

```
setInterval(function () {
    $('#annoying').toggleClass('whiteOne blueOne');
}, 500);
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/5f55k/)**

Answer (score 0):

Even simpler HTML, CSS and JS:

**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsbin.com/aXOjIwo/2/edit)**

```
<p id="annoying">I will flash.</p>
```

```
#annoying {
  color:#0000FF;
}
```

```
(function flash(){
 $('#annoying').delay(300).toggle(0, flash);
}());
```